# Provisioning profile "**" has app ID "**", which does not match the bundle ID "**OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension"

Tags: ios, xcode, onesignal

After I add Today App Extension Target,I become impossible to compile project. below is error(actually I need to to set manual signing in Xcode and set the ad-hoc provisioning profile for "release" type builds for Apple to recognize the Voip cert for using One signal to send voip push notification .):

> Provisioning profile "**" has app ID "**", which does not match the bundle ID "**OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension".

apparently  "**OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" has different bundle ID from the other one target.

I'm really thankfully for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new provisioning profile using with service extension BundleID.

Comment: you mean, I have to create new Apple ID associated to service extension BundleID first ??

Comment: Yes, new appid for extension